# How to extract number suffix from a filename

Tags: java

In Java I have a filename example ABC.12.txt.gz, I want to extract number 12 from the filename. Currently I am using last index method and extracting substring multiple times.

Comment: Thought about using a regular expression?

Comment: What's the problem with your current approach? Does it work? Then what is your question?

Comment: Could you include your current attempt as a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using pattern matching

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

// ... Other features

String fileName = "..."; // Filename with number extension
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*(\\d+).*$"); // Pattern to extract number

// Then try matching
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
String numberExt = "";
if(matcher.matches()) {
    numberExt = matcher.group(1);
} else {
    // The filename has no numeric value in it.
}

// Use your numberExt here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just separate every numeric part from alphanumeric ones by using a regular expression:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "ABC.12.txt.gz";
    String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

    // view the resulting parts
    for (String s : parts) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // do what you want with those values...
}
```

This will output

```
ABC.
12
.txt.gz
```

Then take the parts you need and do what you have to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

We can use something like this to extract the number from a string

```
 String fileName="ABC.12.txt.gz";
 String numberOnly= fileName.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```